# Angular "new row" functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently building a widget for a site that's effectively a "deal builder". In the builder widget will be a "add new item" button which will add a new `device` item to the `<li>` list.

```
 <ul class="deal-builder-devices entity">
     <li ng-repeat="device in devices">
         <div class="db-handset-image">
             <span class="phone-silhouette" ng-hide="hideSilhouette"></span>
                 <img ng-repeat="image in modelImages" src="[[image]]" ng-hide="!hideSilhouette" />
             </span>
         </div>
         <div class="db-device">
             <ul class="opts">
                 <li>
                     <select ng-model="selectedManufacturer" ng-change="getManufacturerModels(selectedManufacturer)">
                         <option value="">Manufacturer</option>
                         <option ng-repeat="manufacturer in manufacturers" value="[[manufacturer.id]]">[[manufacturer.name]]</option>
                     </select>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <select ng-disabled="!models > 0" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-change="loadModelImage(selectedModel)">
                          <option value="">Model</option>
                          <option ng-repeat="model in models" value="[[model.id]]">[[model.model]]</option>
                       </select>
                  </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="deal-builder-controls entity">
      <button class="db-add-handset" ng-click="addDevice()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add another handset</button>
      <button class="db-find-deals">Find deals</button>
  </div>
```

The issue that I'm having is that it gives the select options the exact same model, so if I change the select option in one dropdown, it will change all newly generated dropdowns too. How do I fix this?

This is how `$scope.addDevice();` is currently working:

```
$scope.devices = [0];
$scope.devicesCounter = 0;

$scope.addDevice = function () {

    $scope.devicesCounter++;
    $scope.devices.push($scope.devicesCounter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the same model on all the dropboxes so that is normal
use in

```
ng-model="device.selectedModel"
```

then it will set it to the device and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you push images, manufacturers and models inside of `$scope.devices`.

Also use `angular.copy()` to copy object instead of passing reference. That way you can modify each object individually.

One more thing i changed is `track by $index` after `ng-repeat`. This is necessary since we are pushing identical object into array which is not allowed within `ng-repeat`. You can change devices array to object with some generic keys if you want to avoid `track by`.

And lastly, set `ng-model` to `device.childProperty`. Now you have all data you need inside `devices` array.

Here is the example [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6yIpiMl1LjBgbleyjGz?p=preview)

Comment: If you add new handsets (3 for example) and change the dropdown, they all change?

Comment: @leaksterrr I accidentally didn't use `angular.copy` inside of `addDevice` function. You can check out plunker, now it's fine.